# Dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu on separate disks (Secure boot ON, UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So, I have a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 with Windows 11 Home Single Language pre-installed on an NVMe SSD (/dev/nvme0n1). It has an empty SATA slot, in which I installed a SATA SSD. Now I want to install Ubuntu (dual boot) on the second SSD (/dev/sda) and be able to use both the OSs as and when required. Also, I chose Ubuntu because I won't have to disable Secure Boot. I virtualized this scenario in Vmware Workstation Pro, with every configuration being similar to my actual case. After installing Ubuntu on the second drive (/dev/sda), the GRUB appears with Windows Boot Manager, and all other general options, including ubuntu, appearing in it, but on selecting Windows Boot Manager, it says:

`error: no such device: A87C-2C47.` 
`` error: file `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found. `` 
`Press any key to continue...`

And then I'm taken back to the GRUB menu.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

PS - I can get Windows to boot when I select it manually from the UEFI Boot List (or if I set to first priority, but then again, I wont be able to boot into Ubuntu)

If possible, please provide me a detailed guide on how to complete my desired task, without any error so that I dont brick my actual device.

Okay, so just for confirming that it's not some issue that'll get fixed by reinstalling, I deleted all the VM files. Created a new one, added an NVMe drive, and a SATA drive, turned secure boot on, and installed Windows 11 (UEFI) on NVMe drive. Then I installed Ubuntu on SATA drive (in the previous installation, I installed it using the erase disk, followed by the selection of SATA disk, method, but this time I manually partitioned the drive) alloting 1GB to /boot/efi, 30GB to / and rest 9 GB to swap. Still the same issue. But, I noticed (in the previous scenario also) that after installation, in the first boot, windows does boot up from grub, or even if i restart and again select windows, it'll boot up. But, as soon as I boot up in ubuntu, the error begins there of windows unable to boot up (with the same error as i mentioned).

Output of `sudo blkid`:
[image: Output of 'sudo blkid']

So now, I installed Ubuntu on the second SSD (/dev/sda), this time on bare metal, and everything was working fine, after all the updates, i restarted into ubuntu (as it was the first boot priority), and a couple more restarts to verify that nothing's breaking down. Then, I moved windows to the first priority in boot order, windows booted without any problems, a couple restarts to check that it's working properly also went well. Now, i pressed the power button, pressed F12 to get the one-time-boot-menu, selected ubuntu, and then.....

[It's getting stuck at this screen..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZTer.jpg)

I waited for 10 minutes, no luck :), restarted a couple times, still no luck :/...

What do I do?

Comment: I tried turning off the secure boot, still no luck

Comment: Does your EFI partition have the UUID A87C-2C47 ?  From a terminal in Ubuntu (ctrl+alt+t to start one), type sudo blkid to see all the partitions. Which Ubuntu release are you installing (22.04 has bug 1396379, and write nothing into the second disk's EFI).

Comment: Do you have Windows fast startup hibernation or bitlocker on? Those must be off in Windows.

Comment: @ubfan1 Check out the edited post I wrote. Now, the error is "error: no such device: DCA0-A48E" and the rest is same. And, for your question, I am attaching a photograph in the post for 'sudo blkid' output (I dont know if i can attach a photograph in the comments #newbie), and I'm using Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Please answer comment questions by editing your original post, text with code tags preferred over screenshots. The DCA0-A48E uuid does exist, so does the partition have the boot and esp flags, and does it actually contain the EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi file? Note oldfred's hibernation and bitlocker comment.

Comment: /boot/efi/EFI directory in Ubuntu has only two entries - 'BOOT' & 'ubuntu'

Comment: @oldfred I dont know if its because of VM or what but i am not seeing any option other than sleep and lock in advanced power settings. Should I try installing Ubuntu on my bare metal?

Comment: The only solution I'm thinking of right now is that I'll use the UEFI Boot Manager to select Ubuntu whenever required by pressing F12 on boot. (keeping Windows as the top priority)

Comment: Bitlocker is also turned off (both on laptop and vm)

Comment: I would leave GRUB out of the equation and just boot with the UEFI boot list. One more key to press (*F12*); same need for user attention / interaction.

Comment: I too feel so, going to install directly on laptop. Thanks guysss

Comment: Another problem guys :/ Check the edited post

Comment: Did Windows update (which you may not always see) turn fast startup back on or bitlocker? And are you mounting any NTFS partitions with fstab? Or even the mount of the ESP may be locked by Windows. Double check Windows settings. Sometimes Windows updates also update UEFI, reverting it to defaults. Then you also have to redo any UEFI settings changes you need for Linux.